# How to archive programs on a TI-Nspire?

Tags: calculator, archive, texas-instruments, ti-basic, ti-nspire

I have a TI-Nspire CX. I have some important files on it, which I only need to be able to read (I don't need to edit them for the time being). However, I'm also using my TI-Nspire in my math class and my teacher makes me clear my calculator at the end of the class. Is there any way to archive programs **on a TI-Nspire** or to make it so that they don't get cleared.

The file is something that was made on a computer (think of it like a program for a game).

Note: You cannot archive programs and files on a TI-Nspire like you do on other calculators.

Disclaimer: The program has nothing to do with the test. In fact, I don't need to access the files until 2 hours after my calculus class but I still need it to be on there for a different class.

If this is impossible, can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are typing something in scratchpad's calculator and teacher ask you to clear the history? Firstly, you can save the scratchpad's  sessions. Press ctrl+home/file/save and TI will open a new document with your calculator and graph content, which you can save. Then, close the document, go back to scratchpad and clear the history in front of your teacher.
EDIT: after careful reading, it seems i misunderstood the question. What kind of "clear" your teacher wants you to perform, hard reset? Thats a pretty complicated procedure, i really doubt that teacher is that much into TI calcs that she would know it. Please, clarify it.

Comment: Yeah, the teacher wants me to clear the RAM, but I want a Document to be saved. The equivalent of clearing the RAM on other calculators is 2nd+7+1+2

Comment: Well, you cant clear the RAM on TI NSPire, you can clear history and variables, but that doesnt affect programs on the storage anyway. THe only way to erase the storage is from maintenance menu, which is almost impossible without 3-rd hand assistance. So, just save your documets from the file menu as described above.